# Method returning character using if condition

Tags: java

I need help with the method classify() to return a character. I don't think it reads the if condition. No matter what value the net weekly salary becomes the method still returns 'F'.

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
    String name=sc.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter Weekly Gross: ");
    double gross= sc.nextDouble();
    double gross1=netWeekly(gross);
    char classy=classify(gross1);
    double bonus = gross*0.085;
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("*****SNOW ENTERPRISES*****");
    System.out.println("Employee Name: "+name);
    System.out.println("Gross Salary: "+gross);
    System.out.println("Bonus: "+bonus);
    System.out.println("Net Weekly Salary: "+gross1);
    System.out.println("Classification: "+classy);
}
public static double netWeekly(double a){
    double net=0;
    net = a/4.5; 
    return net;
}
public static char classify(double net){
    double crah=netWeekly(net);

    char letter = 'F';
    if(crah>1500&&crah<1999)
        letter = 'A';

    else if(crah>=2000&&crah<2500)
        letter = 'B';
    else if(crah>=2500&&crah<3000)
        letter = 'C';
    else if(crah>=3000&&crah<3500)
        letter = 'D';
    else if(crah>=3500&&crah<4000)
        letter = 'E';
    else if(crah>=4000)
        return letter = 'F';

    return letter;
}

}
```

Comment: What is the value of `crah` that returns `'F'` incorrectly and what should it return?

Comment: The obvious answer is ```crah``` does not have the value you think it does.  Use a debugger or insert a print statement to see if that is a correct diagnosis.

Comment: In order for `crah` to be less than 4,000, `gross1` needs to be less than 18,000. In order for that to be true, `gross` has to be less than 81,000. Is your input less than 81,000?

Comment: Our professor gave us the output as:
*****SNOW ENTERPRISES*****
Employee Name: Jon
Gross Salary: 10869.37
Bonus: 923.896450000002
Net Weekly Salary: 2423.89645
Classification: B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `netWeekly()` twice:

```
double gross1=netWeekly(gross);  // once here
```

and then again inside the `()` method:

```
public static char classify(double net) {
    double crah=netWeekly(net); // the value passed in is gross1
```

This is the equivalent of executing `netWeekly(netWeekly(gross))`, which makes the value `20.25` times greater than the value entered (rahter than the expected `4.5` times greater).

Remove one of the calls to netWeekly(). I would suggest removing the second call, because it makes the method do just one thing, ie convert an amount to a code, which is good design practice.

Answer (score 0):

Just removed the return after the final elseif and made it to else. Might work, hit and trial.

Try doing this:

```
char letter = 'F';

    if(crah>1500&&crah<1999)
        letter = 'A';

    else if(crah>=2000&&crah<2500)
        letter = 'B';
    else if(crah>=2500&&crah<3000)
        letter = 'C';
    else if(crah>=3000&&crah<3500)
        letter = 'D';
    else if(crah>=3500&&crah<4000)
        letter = 'E';

    else (crah>=4000)
        letter = 'F';

 return letter;
```

And please share what happened, I am keen to learn as well! :) 
Peace!

Comment: This doesn't make a difference. Those if-elses are all mutually exclusive.

Comment: And the OP's issue was that his code always returns 'F', so there's no way that making it "more possible" to return F is going to help.  (Though having said that, I prefer the style of ending with ```else``` rather than ```else if```, and removing the initialization of ```letter```)